# How to Fix Product Page Title direction in WooCommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Since my site is built in such way that the language in it goes from RIGHT TO LEFT, I'm having an issue with the titles of my products pages using WooCommerce on Wordpress.

How can I fix it?

Here's an image representing what I mean:
[image: ordp]
I want the title of the product (Apple Magic Keyboard) to be presented on the left (aligned with the text below it).

Comment: Already considered CSS? text-align property

Comment: You will need to supply CSS code showing this element.

Comment: Yeah I understood that but I don't know what's the class of the WooCommerce Product page title

Comment: Right mouse click on title, inspect element

Comment: lol idk how I didn't think about that option. Thanks though, it worked :)